# NetLogo: Running a BehaviorSpace experiment headless requires r extension on Linux

Tags: java, r, linux, netlogo

I am running a netlogo model on Linux through command lines.

```
NetLogo\ 6.0.4/netlogo-headless.sh \
--model model_r_1.0.nlogo \
--experiment experiment_emd_one \ 
--table test1.csv
```

The model requires r extensions on Netlogo.

Currently, I have R 3.5.0 and Java JDK 1.8.0 loaded. 
And I specified 4GB virtual memory for using JDK 1.8.0 by

```
qlogin -l h_vmem=4G
```

And I have installed packages **rJava**, **JavaGD** and **CommonJavaJars** in R.

And I also changed the ***user.properties*** file under the r extension directory in NetLogo 6.0.4 to specify the path of R and rJava library.

But I still get errors for running. As shown here:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b95b8d7f106, pid=5772, tid=47922117170944
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_74-b02) (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.74-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libR.so+0x1ff106]  Rf_installTrChar+0x6
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /exports/eddie3_homes_local/s1518063/hs_err_pid5772.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
NetLogo 6.0.4/netlogo-headless.sh: line 43:  5772 Aborted                 (core dumped) $JAVA "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -Dnetlogo.extensions.dir="${BASE_DIR}/app/extensions" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.nlogo.headless.Main "${ARGS[@]}"
```

Any idea would be much appreciated!

Comment: I saw [you posted another question about using BehaviorSpace and R together on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989780/no-stop-when-running-netlogo-behaviorspace-headless-on-linux-when-using-r-extens), which makes it sound like you got past this error.  If so, would you be able to post the steps you took to get everything working?  The information might be very useful for other people trying to do the same thing.  Thank you!

Comment: I am still struggling with submitting job script sh file to the cluster to get the experiments done. I will update here if I get it solved. Many thanks for your suggestions.