# No stop when running Netlogo Behaviorspace headless on Linux when using r extension

Tags: linux, netlogo, headless, behaviorspace

I am running a simple netlogo behaviorspace experiment on a Linux cluster with calling R extension.

Here is the sample code:

```
extensions [r]    
to setup
      clear-all
      setup-patches
      setup-turtles
      reset-ticks
    end

    to setup-patches
      ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
    end

    to setup-turtles
      create-turtles number    ;; uses the value of the number slider to create turtles
      ask turtles [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
    end

    to go
      if ticks >= 5 [ stop ]  ;; stop after 5 ticks
      move-turtles
      tick                    ;; increase the tick counter by 1 each time through
    end

    to move-turtles
      ask turtles [
        right random 360
        forward 1
      ]
    end
```

And I set up a BehaviorSpace experiment named *count_turtles*. Set the variables as ["number" 10].
And then I run the experiment on Linux as

```
NetLogo\ 6.0.4/netlogo-headless.sh \
--model model_test.nlogo \
--experiment count_turtles \ 
--table test.csv
```

However, it just keep running on Linux. But after I cut it I can get a proper test.csv. But it just doesn't stop by itself.

But when I run the same experiment on Windows it seems all good.

And if I remove the calling of r extension then it can stop properly. Once I called r extension then it does not stop by itself. But I tested the connection between netlogo and R it seems fine.
I'm wondering why it does not stop by itself.

Comment: Can you try using the **Time limit** or **Stop condition** parameters of the BehaviorSpace experiment setup?  [Docs here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html). They should replicate exactly what you're doing in code, and might work better on Linux with the R extension.

Comment: Many thanks! I don't think I can set up the time limit as I wanna make an experiment with many times running eventually and it's hard to estimate the time. And for stop condition I wanna set it as reaching a specific number of ticks. Not sure how do I set it up?

Comment: Yeah, in double-checking the docs it's unclear, but **Time limit** is actually a limit in `ticks`, so if you set it to 5, that should give you what you're looking for.  Using the **Stop condition** instead would just involve adding NetLogo code like `ticks >= 5` in the box for the experiment, instead of in your model code.  Hopefully one or the other will get around the issue you are having.

Comment: Correct, the time limit is in ticks, not wall time. So just use that.